# Transformer les phrases en utilisant les pronoms relatifs

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

> Transformez les phrases en utilisant les pronoms relatifs.  Exemple:
>   Je l'aime et il m'aime. --> C'est quelqu'un **que** j'aime et **qui**
>   m'aime.

Je ne suis pas sûr de mes réponses:

> > 1. Je lui ressemble et il me ressemble. 
> >        --> C'est quelqu'un à qui je ressemble et qui me ressemble.

Ou plutôt : C'est quelqu'un que je ressemble et qui me ressemble ? Est-ce qu'on dit ressembler quelqu'un ou ressembler à quelqu'un ?

> 2. Je lui dis tout et il me dit tout. --> C'est quelqu'un que je dis tout et qui me dit tout.

Même question. Il me semble que c'est correct mais 
*C'est quelqu'un à qui je dis tout et qui me dit tout* me paraît aussi correct.

> 3. Je le trouve méchant et il ne m'apprécie pas non plus.--> C'est quelqu'un qui je trouve méchant et qui ne m'apprécie pas non plus.

Ou : *C'est quelqu'un que je trouve méchant et qui ne m'apprécie pas non plus* ?

Merci !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Je lui ressemble et il me ressemble. --> C'est quelqu'un à qui je
>   ressemble et qui me ressemble.

Celle-ci est tout à fait correct !

> Je lui dis tout et il me dit tout. --> C'est quelqu'un **à qui** je dis tout et qui me dit tout.

On parle **à** quelqu'un, et dit **à** quelqu'un, donc on va utiliser *à qui je dis tout*.

> Je le trouve méchant et il ne m'apprécie pas non plus.--> C'est quelqu'un **que** je trouve méchant et qui ne m'apprécie pas non plus.

Il faut utiliser *que* à la place de *qui*. 
En français, on n'utilise jamais *qui je trouve*, ce sera toujours *que*, ta seconde suggestion était la bonne !

Comment: Merci mon ami! :)